# android notifications won't run .notify

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to send an android notification but it keeps failing at the mbuilder.build() part.    I do have an alert dialog right after in the same method.  I'm posting my code below

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.noteiconcon)
    .setContentTitle("Finished search")
    .setContentText("We found your account");
    System.out.println("failed after setText");
  // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  System.out.println("failed after result intent");
  // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
 // started Activity.
 // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
 // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    System.out.println("taskstackbuilder passed");

  stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
     System.out.println("stackbuilder.appParentstack passed");

 stackbuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
      System.out.println("stackbuilder.addnextintent passed");
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
    0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);
    System.out.println("pending intent passed");
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
     System.out.println("mbuilder.setcontentintent passed");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("notification manager passed");
 // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
       mNotificationManager.notify(mId,mBuilder.build());
      System.out.println("notificationManager.notify passed"+ mId);
```

I already added the meta data task but the log cat says.

```
    Bogus static initialization, type 4 in field type Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImpl; for Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat; at index 1
```

Like I said I added the meta data tag and this is being called in an asychtask after an alert dialog.  Ive commented out the alert dialog but it still works.

If I drop the last line .notify it doesn't crash but obviously doesn't send a notification.

Comment: Is your device on a custom ROM? If so, which one?

Comment: No it's not. Its stock

Comment: Interesting. Which version of Android? And which device?

Comment: Sony xperia z1 and 4.4

Comment: Do you have any other devices you can try this code on? The error sounds to me like it's trying to initialize a NotificationCompatImpl field with some other type, such as int, which should never happen. If you're on stock, it may be worth a bug report to Sony / Google. It would be nice to try it on the latest version of KitKat, though, which I think is 4.4.4. I have 4.4.2 on my SGS3, at least.

Comment: @TreborRude I have a nexus 2013 but i don't have the code over there, i yeah aide would let you synch to drop box.... But yeah if its that important i can see what i can do

Comment: Where would i submit it to Google

Comment: Even if AIDE doesn't let you do it, the DropBox app should let you sync the AppProjects folder. Or you might be able to use a private GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a different notification method which it accepted the notification then.

```
       // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String MyText = "Finished searching";
    Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.passicon, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );
    //The three parameters are: 1. an icon, 2. a title, 3. time when the notification appears

    String MyNotificationTitle = "Finished Searching";
    String MyNotificationText  = "We can't find your password.";

    Intent MyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,MyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    //A PendingIntent will be fired when the notification is clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent

       mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);

    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , mNotification);  
    //We are passing the notification to the NotificationManager with a unique id.
```

Comment: Show the new code, please. At least the new notification mehtod.